# Why is server.close() executing earlier than server.on('connection')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, libnet

I'm learning the Node.js "Net" library. Can anyone explain to me why in this example **`server.close()`** executing earlier than **`server.on('connection')`**?

I know how to make everything work properly, but I do not understand why the client socket connects to the server **after the server is closed, and not before**.

```
let server = require('./server') // let server = new net.Server().listen(2000)
let client = require('./client') // let client = new net.Socket()
let client2 = require('./client2') // let client2 = new net.Socket()

server.on('listening', () => console.log('Server listening'))

client.on('connect', () => console.log('Client connected'))
client2.on('connect', () => console.log('Client2 connected'))

client.connect(2000)
client2.connect(2000)

server.on('error', (err) => console.log('Server error: ' + err))
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Client error: ' + err))
client2.on('error', (err) => console.log('Client2 error: ' + err))

server.close(() => console.log('Server closed'))
```

Running the file will display the following in the terminal:

```
Server closed
Client2 error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:2000
Client error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:2000
```

But, if I comment on the last line, then the terminal will display:

```
Server listening
Client connected
Client2 connected
```

Comment: Because you call it

Comment: You call `server.close` immediately, at the end of your code (still in the same synchronous context as before), before the event loop had a chance to process the connection event or even the TCP stack had a chance to send and receive your packets since you never yielded execution in between.

Comment: @JaromandaX
I understand what I'm calling it. But why does it work before?
According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/net.html#serverclosecallback ) `server.close()` is an asynchronous function. But why exactly this asynchronous function is called faster than all the others?

Comment: It's called just after the others. The others have had no chance to do anything asynchronous though

Comment: @JaromandaX
Okay, did I understand correctly that if you do not explicitly set the sequence of calls to asynchronous functions, then this is like playing Russian roulette? The result is unpredictable!

Comment: @GeorgiiGalechyan - no, you don't understand correctly.

Answer (score -1):

All these commands are executed *asynchronously*, that's why they have a callback function as second parameter, this will be called when the asynchronous operation is finished. Determining which of the parallel asynchronous executions is faster is a fool's game.

To be sure that an aynchronous command B is executed only after another asynchronous command A has finished, you must execute B in the callback of A. In your case this means

- Connect `client` in the callback of `server`
- Connect `client2` in the callback of `server`
- Close `server` in the callback of `client` and of `client2`

The last bullet point requires that you wait for both callbacks to be invoked, which can be done with `Promise.all` if you "promisify" the client connection.

```js
function connect(client, port) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.connect(port)
    client.on('connect', resolve)
    client.on('error', reject)
  })
}
let server = new net.Server().listen(2000, function() {
  let client = new net.Socket()
  let client2 = new net.Socket()
  Promise.all([
    connect(client, 2000).then(
      () => console.log('Client connected'),
      (err) => console.log('Client error: ' + err)
    ),
    connect(client2, 2000).then(
      () => console.log('Client2 connected'),
      (err) => console.log('Client2 error: ' + err)
    )
  ]).then(() => server.close(() => console.log('Server closed')))
})
server.on('listening', () => console.log('Server listening'))
server.on('error', (err) => console.log('Server error: ' + err))
```

This code produces the three lines that you expect. You will *not* see `Server closed`, however, because the existing connections prevent the server from being closed.

Comment: [Your new code has the same behavior as the old code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huQxc.png). The server is still closed before the two clients can fully establish a connection.

Comment: Hello. You have the same problem as me. And I don't like that we create the Client inside the Server. The Client and the Server must exist as independent entities, otherwise it is devoid of logic.

Comment: You are right, of course, I should have tested my code before replying. I have corrected that in my edited answer.

Comment: @GeorgiiGalechyan: The client is not created _inside_ the server, but _after_ the server has started listening. Because of the server callback function it looks somewhat inside-ish, but this could be avoided by "promisifying" the server creation as well and using `await`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen
I've made your code a bit more complex by increasing the number of Clients to 6.
https://gist.github.com/GeorgiiGalechyan/0facc9052f2878391c753c5af25e676e
After running the code a few times, I find that the connection order changes. For example, the terminal displays:
```
Server listening
Client2 connected
Client1 connected
Client4 connected
Client3 connected
Client6 connected
Client5 connected
5
```

Comment: Yes, the order of client connections finishing is essentially random, that's why I call predicting it a "fool's game".

Comment: @HeikoTheißen
Okay, did I understand correctly that if you do not explicitly set the sequence of calls to asynchronous functions, then this is like playing Russian roulette? The result is unpredictable!

Comment: It's like sending out N HTTP requests in parallel, you cannot predict in which order their responses come back.